# Drupal - Creating a book list

Tags: drupal-7

I'm creating my first drupal website and I've come to a roadblock. I'm creating a multi-author website that authors can list their books on. So far they can list books with a cover image, however I'm stuck when I try and make a list of these books somewhere for users to easily view them.

What I need to do:

1. Create a menu item that users can click on, "Books"
2. Direct them to url.com/books
3. Display a list containing the cover images of the most recently released books, 4 per row. The user can then click on an image to view more details of the book.

I have a custom content type, "book" that has title, blurb, author, and cover fields.

I also want to create a menu on the left side that has a list of authors or genres (similar to what is on Amazon.com). When the user clicks on an author or genre, it narrows the search results down.

What do I need to do this? I'm not familiar enough with Drupal's terminology yet.

Answer (score 1):

Questing is too big, bug any way, you can use following code get list of books.

```
$result = db_query("
SELECT nid 
FROM node 
WHERE type = :type limit  4 OFFSET :offset", 
array(':type' => 'book',':offset' => $offset))->fetchAll();
```

And I guess you may need to create a menu on the left, so following code just a simple example.

```
function books_menu() {
 $items = array();
 $items['books'] = array(
        'title' => t('books'),
       'page callback' => 'your_call_back_method',
        'access arguments' => array('books'),
        'weight' => 0,
    );
 return $items;
}



function your_call_back_method() {
 $pagecontent = ''; // your page layout.
 return $pagecontent ;
}
```

Comment: So you need to use code for this? That's probably why I'm so lost. I figured drupal would have this functionality built in?

Comment: if you want to only use config and not write code, I think you can try model views https://drupal.org/project/views. But I guess you still need to rewrite some theme function for your books list.